# Cropping an image using Jcrop and Imagemagick

Tags: php, jquery, image, imagemagick, jcrop

I'm confused on how the -crop function works in Imagemagick.

I have the following values from Jcrop.

```
(x1,y1), (x2,y2), width and height.
```

And following command:

```
exec("convert $target_path -crop ".$w."x".$h."+$x+$y +repage $target_path");
```

Original image:

[image]

Result after crop:

[image]

My question is, How do I used the coordinates and dimensions from Jcrop, and use them with Imagemagick?

Comment: What was the question? What output did you get? What did you expect/want?

Comment: My question is, How do I used the coordinates and dimensions from Jcrop, and use them with Imagemagick?  I'm using the command above, but the image is not being cropped correctly.

Comment: Please show your input image and the output image and tell us what is wrong with it - then we may be able to help you. At the moment you are effectively saying you used some values we can't see to crop an image we don't know and it didn't come up how you expect...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added screen shots of before and after

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what values you are passing into `convert`, but your command needs to look something like this to extract the light region -if that is your aim:

```
convert x.png -crop 240x240+120+100 out.png
```

[image]

The first `240` is the width of the cropped area, and the second `240` is its height. The `120` is the x-offset across from the top-left corner and the `+100` is the y-offset down from the top.

Or, in general terms, you specify the crop like this

```
convert input.png -crop ${x}x${y}+${a}+${b} output.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot.

I had **style='max-width:500px;'** on my image during the crop.  Removed the style and now it's working.